# Is length member from the String class an integer constant?

Tags: java

I am trying to understand if length member from the String class an integer constant? I'm thinking it is not.

Comment: I am afraid that I am not clear what you are asking? String.length() returns an int primitive and the String class is immutable in Java, but the returned int value itself is not constant.

Comment: You could check the source. Since Strings are immutable, it very well could be `final`.

Comment: I got it, thank you! I might go off topic here but don't want to open another one. I have a simple question. What is the level for precedence for ! and &&?

Comment: ! is executed earlier than &&. Do you have an exam?

Comment: Thanks, Lajos. Nope, that's from the book, practice stuff.

Comment: You can test these stuff easily. boolean a = true, b = false; System.out.println((!b&&a) ? "negation is first" : "conjunction is first");// America first

Comment: Thank you for the info, Lajos, that helps!

Comment: @LajosArpad - Looking it up in a text book, the Oracle Java Tutorial, or the JLS is a better approach to the "just test it" approach.  It is easy for a newbie to get the wrong idea based on the results of a misguided test.  There are all sorts of surprising edge cases that are difficult to discover by (undirected) testing.

Answer (score 6):

It is NOT a *compile time constant expression* in the sense of [JLS 15.28](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28).

The expression `str.length()` is a method call, and no explicit method calls are constant expressions.  This is true even if the String is a literal; i.e. `"hello".length()` is NOT a compile time constant expression according to the JLS.

---

It is a *runtime constant*, in the sense that once the `String` has been created, the length cannot change.  This follows from the fact that Java strings are immutable.

You can confirm this by looking at the source code of any version of the (standard) `String` class.  The code is liable to differ between versions, but the "runtime constancy" property will remain the same across all versions.

---

<sup>(Actually, the above is not completely accurate.  If you are willing to use *bad* reflection to break encapsulation, you can modify the private members of a `String` and mutate it.  That can change the value returned by `length()`.  You could achieve the same effect via native code methods, and possibly other means.  But ... just ... don't do it!  The JLS says that if you do that kind of thing, the behavior of your Java code is *unspecified*.)</sup>

Answer (score 4):

According to the [source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/jdk/file/d966fc5a7be5/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/String.java) (jdk9) for the `String` class, [`length()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length()):

```
public int length() {
    return value.length >> coder();
}
```

Where `value` is

```
@Stable
private final byte[] value;
```

And `coder()` is:

```
byte coder() {
    return COMPACT_STRINGS ? coder : UTF16;
}
```

So it is essentially a runtime constant as `String`'s are immutable and the length of `value` will be decided at compile time.

Comment: Since the source code of `String` has changed over time, you should edit the answer and clarify which version of Java this is.

Comment: @Andreas Good suggestion. Edited

Answer (score -2):

[length](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_length.htm) member from the `String` `class` is a method, returning an `int` value, representing the number of characters of the `String`.

Comment: While a factually true statement, easily obtained from the javadoc, it doesn't in any way answer the question.

Comment: @Andreas the question was about what length is. I think my answer is valid.